# Why is Data.Map.Map not a Bifunctor?

Tags: dictionary, haskell, containers, bifunctor

When storing data in a `Map`, I was recently looking for a `Bitraversable` instance, since I wanted to traverse over both keys and values. To my surprise, I found out that `Map` does not even have a `Bifunctor` instance, even though implementations for both `first` (`mapKeys`) and `second` (`map`) exist.

Is there a specific reason for this or was this decision just made to minimize dependencies?

Thanks

Comment: For lots of typeclasses, we have [`mono-traversable`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mono-traversable) to deal with the monomorphic case, but interestingly, I can't find a `MonoBifunctor` which, while the name is a bit of an oxymoron, seems like it would be a useful typeclass to have.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The implementation for `left` (did you actually mean `first`? I'm going to write `left` instead of `first` everywhere) does not exist, because `mapKeys` has a constraint:

```
Ord k2 => (k1 -> k2) -> Map k1 a -> Map k2 a
```

`left` must work for *any* pair of types `k1` and `k2`.